# Passing a value into a component

Tags: vue.js

I am implementing a component in vue.js and I need to pass in a value to the component from the parent view.  Below is what I am attempting to do.  The `div` correctly receives the id however, the Component does not receive the same id value.  In the final HTML, the id renders as you see it "i-{{item.Id}}-newsletter" and is not parsed by vue.js

What is the correct syntax to send data to the vue.js component?

```
<div class="slds-col" id="{{item.Id}}
     <marketing-preference id="i-{{item.Id}}-newsletter" name="Newsletter" ></marketing-preference>
</div>
```

Here is the Javascript that defines the component.

```
Vue.component('marketing-preference',{
  template: '#marketing-preference-template',
  props:['id','name']
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You need [dynamic props notation](https://vuejs.org/guide/components.html#Dynamic-Props): `:id="'i-' + item.Id + '-newsletter'"`

Comment: I believe you mean `:id="'i-' + item.Id + '-newsletter'"`. Though, OP would be better off creating a method for that or a computed property. I'll still give you some sweet up vote action though.

Comment: @BillCriswell Thanks. Updated. Or could do the other with backticks and ES6.